# NumPy Array Fill Rows Downward By Indexed Sections

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have the following (fictitious) NumPy array:

```
arr = np.array(
    [[1,   2,  3,  4],
     [5,   6,  7,  8],
     [9,  10, 11, 12],
     [13, 14, 15, 16],
     [17, 18, 19, 20],
     [21, 22, 23, 24],
     [25, 26, 27, 28],
     [29, 30, 31, 32],
     [33, 34, 35, 36],
     [37, 38, 39, 40]
    ]
)
```

And for row indices `idx = [0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9]` I'd like to repeat the values in each row downward until it reaches the next row index:

```
np.array(
    [[1,   2,  3,  4],
     [1,   2,  3,  4],
     [9,  10, 11, 12],
     [13, 14, 15, 16],
     [13, 14, 15, 16],
     [21, 22, 23, 24],
     [21, 22, 23, 24],
     [21, 22, 23, 24],
     [33, 34, 35, 36],
     [37, 38, 39, 40]
    ]
)
```

Note that `idx` will always be sorted and have no repeat values. While I can accomplish this by doing something like:

```
for  start, stop in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:]):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        arr[i] = arr[start]

# Handle last index in `idx`
start, stop = idx[-1], arr.shape[0]
for i in range(start, stop):
    arr[i] = arr[start]
```

Unfortunately, I have many, many arrays like this and this can become slow as the size of the array gets larger (in both the number of rows as well as the number of columns) and the length of `idx` also increases. The final goal is to plot these as a heatmaps in `matplotlib`, which I already know how to do. Another approach that I tried was using `np.tile`:

```
for  start, stop in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:]):
    reps = max(0, stop - start)
    arr[start:stop] = np.tile(arr[start], (reps, 1))

# Handle last index in `idx`
start, stop = idx[-1], arr.shape[0]
arr[start:stop] = np.tile(arr[start], (reps, 1))
```

But I am hoping that there's a way to get rid of the slow `for-loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `np.diff` to find the repetition for each row, then `np.repeat`:

```
# this assumes `idx` is a standard list as in the question
np.repeat(arr[idx], np.diff(idx+[len(arr)]), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [33, 34, 35, 36],
       [37, 38, 39, 40]])
```

Comment: Wonderfully concise answer! I think the square brackets can be omitted from `[len(arr)]` since it looks like we are shifting the `idx` over by a constant but otherwise, thank you!

Comment: I was wrong. If `idx` is a list then we are appending to the array. But if `idx` was a 1-D array then we would need to append the `len(arr)` to the end of `idx` there by extending it by a single element maybe with `np.append(idx + len(arr))`.